# Helm in JenkinsX unable to find tiller

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jenkins-x

I am trying to run "helm version" command in the jenkinsx but it fails with the following error.

Error:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

The helm is working in the cluster where jenkinsx is installed but fails only in jenkinsx and I am not sure how to resolve this issue inside jenkinsx

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to your Helm Tiller installation, not really jenkinsx itself. There are two way to solve it: **easy** and **hard**.

The **easy way** is to install [Helm 3, it doesn't use Tiller anymore](http://www.rafalleszko.com/2019/12/19/helm3-five-improvements). So, you'll not encounter this issue.

The **hard way** is to check why your Tiller is not running correctly. There can be multiple reasons for that. Most probably, it was not initialized, because you didn't have enough permissions to install it in your Kubernetes cluster (check [this blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/installing-helm-in-google-kubernetes-engine-7f07f43c536e) for the solution the commands to execute). If it was initialized, but you still cannot access it, then you need to check the logs of the Tiller to check it's up and running.

Answer (score 0):

try `helm version --client` to avoid needing tiller. Jenkins X defaults to not installing tiller as its a massive security issue: https://jenkins-x.io/blog/2018/10/03/helm-without-tiller/

Comment: Actually I need to delete all the resources of a helm release using "helm delete --purge <release>". Please let me know how to do this